# What HTTP Status code to use when a dependency/downstream (like a 3rd party API) fails?

Tags: http, http-status-codes

We have a route in our API which (when called) hits another 3rd party API.

e.g.

`HTTP-GET /account/1`

this returns some data from our database AND from .. say .. a 3rd party api like Auth0/Okta/SalesForce/whatever.

Now, if this 3rd party api call fails for any reason (fails == 4**, 5** or even a 200 OK but the content is some error message) then what error status code should I pass back to the client calling *my* API?

Initially I was thinking an `HTTP-500-Server-Error` but ... I'm not so sure now because I *can* prevent this error from occurring in the server if I return a nice error message back to the client. So then I thought, return an `HTTP-200-OK` which contains some key/value of the downstream issue/error ... but is this *really* OK (pun intended). To me, `HTTP-200-OK` is like the answer returned is *really* ok.

So i'm not sure what people do in this scenario.

I feel like an `HTTP-500` is for errors that occur but haven't really been handled and/or accounted for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, if this 3rd party api call fails for any reason (fails == 4**, 5** or even a 200 OK but the content is some error message) then what error status code should I pass back to the client calling *my* API?

APIs should be designed from the consumer's perspective. In most of situations, the API consumer wont't care if the request is fulfilled by the server they are firing a request to or by a downstream server.

If the request to the downstream server **prevents your server from fulfilling the client request**, you could go for [`500`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1) or [`503`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.4). Alternatively you could return some cached data (if you have any) and return a [`2xx`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3) status code.

Comment: @Evert While writing this answer, I was tempted to suggest `502`: indicates that the server, while acting as a gateway or proxy, received an invalid response from an inbound server it accessed while attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: I actually meant 502, not 504 =) so yea I would agree

Comment: OK - so the summary is: Regardless _why_ the request wasn't fulfilled ... it just wasn't fulfilled. As such, `HTTP 5XX`. IETF says: "`The 5xx (Server Error) class of status code indicates that the server is aware that it has erred`" (ref: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.6)  . This compares to IETF on `4XX` statuses: "`The 4xx (Client Error) class of status code indicates that the client seems to have erred.'" (ref: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5)